# Sudden Run Time Error 1004 - Not finding File

Tags: vba, excel

Trying to figure out why suddenly this code broke.  I am trying to get it to loop through a specified folder, open workbook, cut some data, paste it, save workbook, close workbook.  Then move through to the next file in the specified folder.

It was working beautifully, then suddenly I was getting the Run Time Error 1004 and it was saying that the file wasn't there.  Odd thing is, the code never names the actual file as it is looping through multiples, but it knows the name of the file.  I tried resaving the file with new name, and it picks up that the name is new!  But still won't open.

I'm including the offending code below.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!  It's a work in progress, hence all the comments.

```
Sub ImportSiteData()

Dim MyFile As String
Dim eRowMaster 'final row to paste to
Dim eRowArchive 'final row to paste to archive

MyFile = Dir("C:\Users\belindaastley\Desktop\Influenza\") 'change directory based on where this will live

Do Until Len(MyFile) < 0
    If MyFile = "zDoom.xlsm" Then 'change the zdoom to whatever we are calling the master workbook
        MsgBox ("Importing has been completed.")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Workbooks.Open (MyFile)
    Worksheets("Data").Select
    Dim xrow
    xrow = 2
    Dim LastCutRow As Long
    LastCutRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Do Until xrow = LastCutRow + 1
        Worksheets("Data").Select

        ActiveSheet.Cells(xrow, 1).Select
        If Not isblank Then
            ActiveCell.EntireRow.Cut
            Worksheets("Archive").Select
            ActiveSheet.Range("LastRow").Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste

            'Workbooks("zDoom.xlsm").Activate
            'Worksheets("Data").Select
            'ActiveSheet.Range("LastRow").Select

            'ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial
            'Application.CutCopyMode = False

            'need to copy to empty row in zdoom
        End If
        xrow = xrow + 1
    Loop
    '1. select first row of data
    '2. cut row of data
    '3. paste row of data to archived sheet at last row
    '4. switch to master
    '5. paste row of data to data sheet at last row
    '6. save site spreadsheet
    '7. close site spreadsheet
    '8.
    '

    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWorkbook.Close

    'eRowMaster = Worksheets("Data").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    'ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Data").Range(Cells(eRowMaster, 1), Cells(eRowMaster, 26))
    'need to change cells reference based on what the actual data is going to look like.  may need to be extended

    MyFile = Dir

Loop

'run from the main workbook
'needs to open each site workbook within the reporting folder
'needs to copy the new data, paste into data table in main workbook
'mark each imported data line in the site workbook as imported
'save site workbook
'close site workbook
'move on to the next workbook
'save main workbook

End Sub
```

Comment: Check the folder that holds the workbooks for any files without an extension. Not sure, but Excel may attempt to open with a default extension.

Comment: Which line is throwing the error? Does the workbook contain **only** files that Excel can open with `Workbooks.Open`?

Comment: What is "If Not isblank Then"??

Comment: Also, your line "Workbooks.Open (MyFile)" will not include the path to the file.

Comment: Is `Worksheets("Data")` in the file you are opening using `Workbooks.Open()` or is it in the file where the macro resides? What about `Worksheets("Archive")`? In which Excel file is that sheet? What do you mean by `If Not isblank Then`? Is blank a cell containing `""` or a cell containing `0` or a cell containing anything with `Len(.Formula) > 0`?

Comment: For safety consider having `Dir` filter out files you don't want to open or that Excel can't open: E.g. `MyFile = Dir("C:\Users\belindaastley\Desktop\Influenza\*.xlsx")` will give you Excel files (plain workbooks, no macro-enabled workbooks). Your filter will depend on what you're opening. A side benefit is that you may not need to test for the zDoom.xlsm file, since this gets filtered out.

Comment: `Do Until Len(MyFile) < 0` looks wrong --- should be `= 0`. `Dir` will not return a file name with negative length.

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn the "If Not isblank then" is to only pull data that is there.  I was struggling to find a way so that it wouldn't have to loop through all the rows of data that isn't there.

Comment: `Workbooks.Open (MyFile)` may not find `MyFile` if your path (present working directory) has changed. You can make this more bullet proof by specifying the file path: `Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\belindaastley\Desktop\Influenza\" & MyFile)`

Comment: But is 'isblank' a function that you have written? Have you included an 'Option Explicit' and tried to compile? 'isblank' is not an Excel function.

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn isblank isn't a function I wrote.  I am a very very new vba-er and have just been gleaning wisdom off these forums.  I was just testing to see if there is data there, and then only copying that line if there is something there.  Is there a better way to accomplish this?  I don't want to run into problems later!

Comment: @xidgel I think that fixed the problem!  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: 'IsBlank' is not a VBA statement - it is used in the worksheet. Therefore, I get a compile error with your code - thus the reason for suggesting you use ALWAYS use 'Option Explicit' and then compile your code. This is a simple step that will save you much aggravation in the future. If you use the IsBlank function in a cell, the correct syntax is like '=ISBLANK(B1)'. In VBA you could use something like 'If Not IsEmpty(YourVariable) Then'   Or you could use 'If Len(YourString & "") > 0 Then'